# How many copies of $D_4$ in $S_5$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

This question is motivated by studying the Sylow-$p$-subgroups of $S_5$.

From Sylow's theorems, the order of Sylow-2-subgroups has order 8 and are all conjugate to copies of the dihedral groups of $D_4$: $\langle(1 2 3 4), (2 4)\rangle$.

Furthermore, from Sylow's third theorem, the number of conjugates is congruent to 1 (mod 2) and divides 15, and therefore, is 1, 3, 5 or 15.

The answer then is clearly 15 as there are clearly more than 5.

However, I am wondering if anyone can provide a counting argument that the number of copies of $D_4$ in $S_5$ is 15.

Thank you.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: [You've been told about MathJax before . . . by me.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681642/subgroups-of-the-alternating-groups#comment9900082_4681642)

Comment: Though true, how do you know in principle that 2-Sylows are dihedral?

Comment: It may be simpler to start by asking yourself how many copies of $D_4$ are there in $S_4$. Then how many copies of $S_4$ in $S_5$, but some care is needed in combining those two answers.

Comment: @orione The reason is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973903/a-2-sylow-subgroup-of-s-5-is-isomorphic-to-d-4), for example. They all need to be conjugated to the one with generators $r=(1234)$ and $s=(12)$, which gives the dihedral group of order $8$.

Comment: See also Derek's remark [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664104/what-is-the-number-of-sylow-2-subgroups-of-the-symmetric-group-s-5), why there are $15$ $2$-Sylow subgroups in $S_5$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think there are 3 copies of $D_4$ in $S_4$, by the conjugacy classes. And then 5 copies of $S_4$ in $S_5$, by fixing each $i$ when $i \in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}$. Is this right?

Comment: That is correct. And as you pointed out, the $3\cdot5$ copies resulting from this must be distinct, as they fix a different point (out of five).